# Reuseable datasource in one design

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have two components(table and list) which must be filled by same jrDataSource. Both of my components are in section title

This is how i get access to my jrdatasource which in this case is instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRMapCollectionDataSource

`<parameter name="Dataset1" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>`

Each component has this section

`<datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="...">
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{Dataset1}]]></dataSourceExpression>
 </datasetRun>`

My question is:

Why only the first component is filled by this data source? No matter which it would be, I can reorder them and always it works only for first element i hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this scenario and found that both the list and the table get filled all right. They can also be displayed correctly in the Title band if you place them side by side. However, trouble begins if you place one on top of the other - only the top one gets displayed. My guess is Jasper cannot stretch a band on two elements growing simultaneously so you will have to redesign your report.

Comment: I tried to confirm your answer by placing my list and table side by side and still same problem. Could you share your code ?

Comment: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5RlXDFsoD4pVkxaU1ZMWWRyZ0k/view?usp=sharing) you go. This report uses iReports Sample Database.

Comment: When I render your report from java it has only list rendered, table is empty

Comment: Then you must be reusing the same dataset object and, once it is used, its `hasNext()` is returning `false` and, subsequently, the table is never filled.

Comment: No, since the resetting must be done by Jasper itself while it is evaluating the Title band. I am afraid you will have to rethink your report.